# How do I deserialize list of complex objects with newtonsoft.json

Tags: serialization, json.net

I need to deserialize this JSON using Newtonsoft.json:

```
{
  "Monday": [
    {
      "begin": "08:00:00",
      "end": "17:00:00",
      "duration": "09:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "Tuesday": [
    {
      "begin": "08:00:00",
      "end": "17:00:00",
      "duration": "09:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a class `Times`

   ```
   public class Times
   {
       public string Begin { get; set; }
       public string End { get; set; }
       public string Duration { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Deserialize the JSON into a `Dictionary<string, List<Times>>`.  The keys of the dictionary will be the day names, e.g. `Monday`, `Tuesday`, etc.

   ```
   var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Times>>>(jsonString);
   ```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CRbTZn